# Weird zsh grep -P behaviour

Tags: shell, grep, zsh, regular-expression, quoting

I connect to server with PuTTY from Windows.

I have a long yet not touched (I suppose) by hands of local admin config:

```
$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config
...    
### must be enabled, which is typically done by setting the
### 'enable-auto-props' option.
# *.c = svn:eol-style=native
# *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
...
```

Want to see if there are lines, which begin with something not `#`:

```
$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "$[^#]"
zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at `^#'
$
[1]    broken pipe  cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config

$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "\$[^#]"

$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "\$#"

$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "$#"
### details, see Debian Bug #413102):
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
```

Can anyone explain why 2nd and 3rd outputs are same empty and what is that 4th?

UPD: here file is:

```
### This file configures various client-side behaviors.
###
### The commented-out examples below are intended to demonstrate
### how to use this file.

### Section for authentication and authorization customizations.
[auth]
### Set store-passwords to 'no' to avoid storing passwords in the
### auth/ area of your config directory.  It defaults to 'yes'.
### Note that this option only prevents saving of *new* passwords;
### it doesn't invalidate existing passwords.  (To do that, remove
### the cache files by hand as described in the Subversion book.)
# store-passwords = no
### Set store-auth-creds to 'no' to avoid storing any subversion
### credentials in the auth/ area of your config directory.
### It defaults to 'yes'.  Note that this option only prevents
### saving of *new* credentials;  it doesn't invalidate existing
### caches.  (To do that, remove the cache files by hand.)
# store-auth-creds = no

### Section for configuring external helper applications.
[helpers]
### Set editor to the command used to invoke your text editor.
###   This will override the environment variables that Subversion
###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR,
###   et al).
# editor-cmd = editor (vi, emacs, notepad, etc.)
### Set diff-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff implementation.
# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
### Set diff3-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff3' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff3 implementation.
# diff3-cmd = diff3_program (diff3, gdiff3, etc.)
### Set diff3-has-program-arg to 'true' or 'yes' if your 'diff3'
###   program accepts the '--diff-program' option.
# diff3-has-program-arg = [true | false]
### Set merge-tool-cmd to the command used to invoke your external
### merging tool of choice. Subversion will pass 4 arguments to
### the specified command: base theirs mine merged
# merge-tool-cmd = merge_command

### Section for configuring tunnel agents.
[tunnels]
### Configure svn protocol tunnel schemes here.  By default, only
### the 'ssh' scheme is defined.  You can define other schemes to
### be used with 'svn+scheme://hostname/path' URLs.  A scheme
### definition is simply a command, optionally prefixed by an
### environment variable name which can override the command if it
### is defined.  The command (or environment variable) may contain
### arguments, using standard shell quoting for arguments with
### spaces.  The command will be invoked as:
###   <command> <hostname> svnserve -t
### (If the URL includes a username, then the hostname will be
### passed to the tunnel agent as <user>@<hostname>.)  Here we
### redefine the built-in 'ssh' scheme to avoid an unfortunate
### interaction with the "ControlMaster auto" feature (for
### details, see Debian Bug #413102):
ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -o ControlMaster=no
### If you wanted to define a new 'rsh' scheme, to be used with
### 'svn+rsh:' URLs, you could do so as follows:
# rsh = rsh
### Or, if you wanted to specify a full path and arguments:
# rsh = /path/to/rsh -l myusername
### On Windows, if you are specifying a full path to a command,
### use a forward slash (/) or a paired backslash (\\) as the
### path separator.  A single backslash will be treated as an
### escape for the following character.

### Section for configuring miscelleneous Subversion options.
[miscellany]
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
### Set log-encoding to the default encoding for log messages
# log-encoding = latin1
### Set use-commit-times to make checkout/update/switch/revert
### put last-committed timestamps on every file touched.
# use-commit-times = yes
### Set no-unlock to prevent 'svn commit' from automatically
### releasing locks on files.
# no-unlock = yes
### Set mime-types-file to a MIME type registry file, used to
### provide hints to Subversion's MIME type auto-detection
### algorithm.
# mime-types-file = /path/to/mime.types
### Set preserved-conflict-file-exts to a whitespace-delimited
### list of patterns matching file extensions which should be
### preserved in generated conflict file names.  By default,
### conflict files use custom extensions.
# preserved-conflict-file-exts = doc ppt xls od?
### Set enable-auto-props to 'yes' to enable automatic properties
### for 'svn add' and 'svn import', it defaults to 'no'.
### Automatic properties are defined in the section 'auto-props'.
# enable-auto-props = yes
### Set interactive-conflicts to 'no' to disable interactive
### conflict resolution prompting.  It defaults to 'yes'.
# interactive-conflicts = no

### Section for configuring automatic properties.
[auto-props]
### The format of the entries is:
###   file-name-pattern = propname[=value][;propname[=value]...]
### The file-name-pattern can contain wildcards (such as '*' and
### '?').  All entries which match (case-insensitively) will be
### applied to the file.  Note that auto-props functionality
### must be enabled, which is typically done by setting the
### 'enable-auto-props' option.
# *.c = svn:eol-style=native
# *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
# *.h = svn:eol-style=native
# *.dsp = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.dsw = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
# *.txt = svn:eol-style=native
# *.png = svn:mime-type=image/png
# *.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg
# Makefile = svn:eol-style=native
```

Comment: `$` is "end of line", why are you putting that in front of your pattern?

Comment: @Mat, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside double quotes, the characters `` $"\` `` remain special. You may be confusing them with single quotes: inside single quotes, all characters are interpreted literally, except for `'` itself which ends the string literal.

```
$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "$[^#]"
zsh: bad math expression: operand expected at `^#'
```

`$[…]` is a deprecated syntax for arithmetic expressions, which can be written `$((…))` like in POSIX shells. `^#` is not a valid arithmetic expression; the shell expected an operand, such as a number or a variable name.

```
[1]    broken pipe  cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config
```

Since the second command in the pipeline aborted before consuming all the output from `cat` (it hadn't even started reading), the first command (`cat`) received a [SIGPIPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE).

```
$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "\$[^#]"
$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "\$#"
```

The backslash tells the shell to interpret the next character literally, so `grep` saw the pattern `$[^#]` or `$#`. These patterns mean “the end of the line followed by any character except `#`” and “the end of the line followed by `#`” respectively. Neither of these patterns can match anything.

```
$ cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep -P "$#"
```

`$#` is the number of positional arguments (`$1`, `$2`, …, collectively accessible as `$@`), i.e. the arguments passed on the shell command line, or the arguments to a function if inside a function. In an interactive shell, there are usually no positional arguments, so `grep` saw the pattern `0`.

The pattern you're looking for is `^[^#]` (`^` matches at the beginning of a line). Unless you mean to include the value of a shell variable or the output of a command in the pattern, use single quotes (it doesn't matter here, but it matters for some patterns, especially the ones that contain a backslash or a `$`). You don't need `-P` as this pattern is written in the same way in basic regexps (plain `grep`), extended regexps (`grep -E`) and perl regexps (`grep -P`).

```
$ </opt/jira/.subversion/config grep '^[^#]'
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you exactly what happens to give the output you got in each case. However, there are two problems with what you're doing:

1. The `-P` flag (for Perl-compatible regular expressions) is considered experimental, and isn't needed for what you're trying to do.
2. `$` is the end-of-line character in a regex. You should use the start-of-line character, `^`.

---

```
cat /opt/jira/.subversion/config | grep "^[^#]"
```

or more concisely,

```
grep "^[^#]" /opt/jira/.subverison/config
```

should do what you want.

Comment: That's it! Don't know why I used `$`. But still interesting about outputs.